# Form preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that submits a hidden form:

```
<a href = "javascript:;" onclick = "document.getElementById('work-for-form').submit();">
```

Form:

```
<form id="work-for-form"  action="localhost/update" method="PUT" style="display: none;">
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

And my js:

```
$("#work-for-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
});
```

But the form still loads a new page.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: it is /update, just a typo here

Comment: have you tried return false instead of. preventDefault

Comment: Sounds like you have JS errors that would prevent your code from executing - have you checked the console?

Comment: yes i have, no errors, redirects me straight to update page

Comment: Preventing default in a jQuery handler will never work when you explicitly call the native `submit` handler in the anchor. This is an X/Y problem, it you want to prevent the form from submitting, stop submitting it when clicking the anchor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onclick event on your a is too strong to prevent the submission of the form. I would suggest the following to fix this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" >form submit</a>

<form id="work-for-form"  action="/update" method="PUT" style="display: none;">{{ csrf_field() }}</form>

<script>
$("a").on("click",function(){
    $("#work-for-form").submit();
})
$("#work-for-form").submit(function(event){
    alert('intercept');
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
});
</script>
```

see also https://jsfiddle.net/9hta6f48/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return false` or you can use `eventListeners`

```
<form onsubmit="alert('stop submit'); return false;" >
```

Or

```
function mySubmit(){
      alert('Will not submit');
      return false;
   }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return mySubmit();" >
```

Or event listeners

```
var myFuncRef = function(event) { event.preventDefault() }

element.attachEvent('onclick', myFuncRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be inside $(document).ready or must be after the form is rendered,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#work-for-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
  });
});
```